# I can't login to Drupal as my session cookie was deleted?

Tags: 7, users, cookies, proxies, ssl

I'm using Drupal 7, and have Pound running in front of Varnish for HTTPS.  I can browse the site via HTTPS, but can't login - each time I do, the server returns a 403 forbidden error.  Any ideas as to what is causing this?  I'm guessing something may need to be changed in `settings.php`, but not sure.

Output from Firebug:

**POST user**

*Response Headers*

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Age 0
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 09 Oct 2012 17:49:08 GMT
Etag    "1349804948"
Expires Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 09 Oct 2012 17:49:08 +0000
Location    https://drupal.domain.com/user/2
Server  Apache
Set-Cookie SESSe15687525d17b8ec181665a71c88775c=EttXyyPvqESdU4RapW7xZkrRagGNHgRH5I9P6x0yRRE; expires=Thu, 01-Nov-2012 21:22:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.drupal.domain.com; httponly SSESSe15687525d17b8ec181665a71c88775c=mAdWa_a_OvcIIoWBuiVbLqFJzwyHiukfd_xBOVz_eaQ; expires=Thu, 01-Nov-2012 21:22:28 GMT; path=/; domain=.drupal.domain.com; secure; HttpOnly
Via 1.1 varnish
X-Drupal-Cache  MISS
X-Varnish   2081364495
```

*Request Headers*

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  has_js=1; __utma=194497400.1529654640.1349804906.1349804906.1349804906.1; __utmb=194497400.3.10.1349804906; __utmc=194497400; __utmz=194497400.1349804906.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
DNT 1
Host    drupal.domain.com
Referer https://drupal.domain.com/user
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
```

**GET 2**

*Response Headers*

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Oct 2012 17:49:08 +0000
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
Etag: "1349804948-1"
Content-Language: en
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Set-Cookie: SSESSe15687525d17b8ec181665a71c88775c=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.drupal.domain.com; secure; httponly
SESSe15687525d17b8ec181665a71c88775c=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.drupal.domain.com; httponly
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8916
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2012 17:49:09 GMT
X-Varnish: 2081364496
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

*Request Headers*

```
GET /user/2 HTTP/1.1
Host: drupal.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://drupal.domain.com/user
Cookie: has_js=1; __utma=194497400.1529654640.1349804906.1349804906.1349804906.1; __utmb=194497400.3.10.1349804906; __utmc=194497400; __utmz=194497400.1349804906.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); SESSe15687525d17b8ec181665a71c88775c=EttXyyPvqESdU4RapW7xZkrRagGNHgRH5I9P6x0yRRE; SSESSe15687525d17b8ec181665a71c88775c=mAdWa_a_OvcIIoWBuiVbLqFJzwyHiukfd_xBOVz_eaQ
```

Comment: module rewrite of apache enabled? in the config files of drupal settings.php do you enable the cookie? I have a similar problem that my site broke but it was because I did not have the rewrite module enabled? do you have ssl enabled?

Comment: I am facing same problem... Did you get any solution? Please update...

Comment: @JilaniJidni Pound passes along the client IP appropriately, but it needs to be set in Varnish.

    `if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "https") {  
    remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;  
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;  
    }`

Comment: @am4 would you mind writing your solution and check your answer as the solution. It will help other people facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pound passes along the client IP appropriately, but it needs to be forcibly set for non-https (http) requests to Varnish.

```
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "https") {
  remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I have enabled such settings in my sites/default/settings.php file:

```
$base_url = 'https://shkodenko.com';  // NO trailing slash!
$conf['https'] = TRUE;
```

I have fixed this by adding .htaccess mod_rewrite rules:

```
# Force SSL for user login
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/login
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to configure your Varnish 3 with Drupal 7 by checking this page: [Configure Varnish 3 for Drupal 7](https://fourkitchens.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TECH/Configure+Varnish+3+for+Drupal+7).

Based on your 2nd GET response, the interesting part of it is the header which is:

```
Set-Cookie: SSESSe15687525d17b8ec181665a71c88775c=deleted
```

which means this cookie was deleted (most likely by Varnish), so you need to setup `req.http.Cookie` in your configuration to allow `SESS`/`SSESS`-like cookies, so they can remain for your session, otherwise other cookies may be removed (`unset req.http.Cookie`).

Here is the relevant part of `.vcl` config file to parse respond to incoming Drupal requests:

```
# Respond to incoming requests.
sub vcl_recv {
  # Use anonymous, cached pages if all backends are down.
  if (!req.backend.healthy) {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }

  # Allow the backend to serve up stale content if it is responding slowly.
  set req.grace = 6h;

  # Pipe these paths directly to Apache for streaming.
  #if (req.url ~ "^/admin/content/backup_migrate/export") {
  #  return (pipe);
  #}

  if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    }
    else {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
  }

  # Do not cache these paths.
  if (req.url ~ "^/status\.php$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/update\.php$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/admin$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/admin/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^/flag/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^.*/ajax/.*$" ||
      req.url ~ "^.*/ahah/.*$") {
       return (pass);
  }

  # Do not allow outside access to cron.php or install.php.
  #if (req.url ~ "^/(cron|install)\.php$" && !client.ip ~ internal) {
    # Have Varnish throw the error directly.
  #  error 404 "Page not found.";
    # Use a custom error page that you've defined in Drupal at the path "404".
    # set req.url = "/404";
  #}

  # Always cache the following file types for all users. This list of extensions
  # appears twice, once here and again in vcl_fetch so make sure you edit both
  # and keep them equal.
  if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(pdf|asc|dat|txt|doc|xls|ppt|tgz|csv|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js)(\?.*)?$") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
  }

  # Remove all cookies that Drupal doesn't need to know about. We explicitly
  # list the ones that Drupal does need, the SESS and NO_CACHE. If, after
  # running this code we find that either of these two cookies remains, we
  # will pass as the page cannot be cached.
  if (req.http.Cookie) {
    # 1. Append a semi-colon to the front of the cookie string.
    # 2. Remove all spaces that appear after semi-colons.
    # 3. Match the cookies we want to keep, adding the space we removed
    #    previously back. (\1) is first matching group in the regsuball.
    # 4. Remove all other cookies, identifying them by the fact that they have
    #    no space after the preceding semi-colon.
    # 5. Remove all spaces and semi-colons from the beginning and end of the
    #    cookie string.
    set req.http.Cookie = ";" + req.http.Cookie;
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "; +", ";");   
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(SESS[a-z0-9]+|SSESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE)=", "; \1=");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";[^ ][^;]*", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^[; ]+|[; ]+$", "");

    if (req.http.Cookie == "") {
      # If there are no remaining cookies, remove the cookie header. If there
      # aren't any cookie headers, Varnish's default behavior will be to cache
      # the page.
      unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    else {
      # If there is any cookies left (a session or NO_CACHE cookie), do not
      # cache the page. Pass it on to Apache directly.
      return (pass);
    }
  }
}
```

If you're using other modules which defines alternative cookies (such as [OpenAM](https://www.drupal.org/project/openam)), you need to modify the regex for Cookie pattern accordingly, e.g.

```
set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, ";(_MYCOOKIE_[a-z]+_[a-z]+|SESS[a-z0-9]+|SSESS[a-z0-9]+|NO_CACHE)=", "; \1=");
```